# Cordova with latest Parse SDK (1.7)

Tags: android, cordova, parse-platform

Originally:

`Cordova 4.1.2
Cordova Parse Plugin - http://plugreg.com/plugin/avivais/phonegap-parse-plugin
Parse SDK 1.3`

My Patch:

`Cordova 4.1.2
Cordova Parse Plugin - http://plugreg.com/plugin/avivais/phonegap-parse-plugin
Parse SDK 1.7`

I need to extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver which only available in Parse SDK 1.7 not SDK 1.3.
I updated the the parse sdk from 1.3 to 1.7 as mention above.
I success compile the cordova project and install to android device but crash upon launching.

Anyone sucess develop cordova app with ParseSDK 1.7?

Comment: responded at 

[link](https://github.com/avivais/phonegap-parse-plugin/issues/20)